# Sleep in Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something code like:

```
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    do_something();
    if(i == 500)
    {
        //STOP THIS FOR LOOP FOR 2s
        do_this_function();

    }
}
```

How can i simulate this STOP? 
This stop should work only when i is 500, in other i should just do for loop. I tried use setTimeout, delay, wait, but this stop just this function, dont stop the entire loop.

Maybe should i use recursive function instead of for? Is there another way?

Comment: in Jquery, you can add SetTimeOut(function(){},500) to add delay

Comment: you can use 



for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    do_something();
    if(i == 500)
    {
  wait(2000);      //STOP THIS FOR LOOP FOR 2s
        do_this_function();

    }
}

Comment: wait is not defined :(